# Is there a way to add custom controls to an amchart?

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I'm trying to add a date picker control to my amchart and I'm not sure of how to best do this.

I'd like to add a calendar icon button to the upper left of the chart and have the date picker display as an overlay on top of the chart when clicking on the calendar button.

Do I just use absolute positioning and z-index CSS to position and overlay this control?

Comment: Here's an example chart: http://jsfiddle.net/tweatherly/tr4mfaur/

Comment: Title of your answer does not match with the question itself. Then you ask about CSS attributes what is not indicated with a tag and also doing more hard to understand what you really need.  Also you should add your code in the question directly. You could use a snippet https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @TedWeatherly "Do I just use absolute positioning and z-index CSS to position and overlay this control?" - Pretty much. Or you can do what the [export plugin is doing](https://github.com/amcharts/export) and add your button to the amcharts-main-div div in the same fashion and style it.